# Eclipse delimiter-separated file wizard

Tags: eclipse

Is there wizard that I can reuse that allows me to import delimiter-separated file? A wizard similar to the one used by Excel where you can select first first row as column names and also define custom delimiter?

Comment: What would Eclipse do with this? It is not Excel and doesn't have any spreadsheet or database code in the core Eclipse.

Comment: @greg-449 I understand that Eclipse doesn't have it out of the box, but perhaps someone knows about a project that already has such wizard implemented. May be some simple model is returned when wizard is finished. But I am mostly interested in UI part.